# Error Symfony2 Doctrine Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association sth#vote, but expecting sth\Vote

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

**Hi, I've been searching on Internet and I don't understand why I get this error. I don't see any error in this code. 1 vote can have many answers and 1 answer can have one vote**

The error is:

> Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on
>   association myvote\usuariosBundle\Entity\Answer#vote, but expecting
>   myvote\usuariosBundle\Entity\Vote

My class Answer.php

namespace myvote\usuariosBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

```
/**  
 * Answer  
 *  
 * @ORM\Table()  
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="myvote\usuariosBundle\Entity\AnswerRepository")
 */ 
class Answer {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_vote", type="integer")
     */
    private $idVote;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="count", type="integer")
     */
    private $count;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Vote", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_vote", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $vote; 
 ...
```

My class Vote.php

```
<?php

namespace myvote\usuariosBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**  
 * Vote  
 *  
 * @ORM\Table()  
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="myvote\usuariosBundle\Entity\VoteRepository")
 */ 
 class Vote {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_user", type="integer")
     */
    private $idUser;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="vote")
     */
    protected $answers;
```

Controller.php

```
public function createVoteAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new CreateVoteType());
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()) {
            $postData = $request->request->get('create');
            $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

            $vote = new Vote();
            $vote->setIdUser($session->get('id_user'));
            $vote->setQuestion($postData['title']);
            $vote->setPassword($postData['password']);
            $vote->setDateStart(new \DateTime($postData['date_start']));
            $vote->setDateFinish(new \DateTime($postData['date_finish']));
            $vote->setTimeRest($postData['time_rest']);
            $vote->setDateTime(new \DateTime("now"));
            $vote->setType($postData['type_vote']);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($vote);
            $em->flush();

            for($i=1;$i<=$postData['total_option'];$i++){
                $answer = new Answer();
                $answer->setIdVote($vote);
                $answer->setAnswer($postData['option'.$i]);
                $answer->setCount(0);
                $em->persist($answer);
                $em->flush();
            }

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myvoteusuarios_createvotepage'));
        }

        return $this->render('myvoteusuariosBundle:Default:create_vote.html.twig', array(
            'createVoteForm' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

**The vote is stored correctly, but no answers(appears the error)
What can it be?
Thanks!**

Comment: Can you reduce this to simpler example.  That may help you figure it out and if not would help us. At first glance your code looks correct.

Comment: would you please print your error stack?!

Comment: Alaa Attya Mohamed the error is:
Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association myvote\usuariosBundle\Entity\Answer#vote, but expecting myvote\usuariosBundle\Entity\Vote


$state = $this->getEntityState($entry, self::STATE_NEW);
if ( ! ($entry instanceof $assoc['targetEntity'])) {
   throw new ORMException(
   sprintf(
  'Found entity of type %s on association %s#%s, but expecting %s',
       get_class($entry),
500 Internal Server Error - ORMException

Comment: Peter Wooster the problem is here because the code above works:
for($i=1;$i<=$postData['total_option'];$i++){
 $answer = new Answer();
 $answer->setIdVote($vote);
 $answer->setAnswer($postData['option'.$i]);
 $answer->setCount(0);
 $em->persist($answer);
 $em->flush();
}