# Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association but expecting

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have problem relating to one-to-many self referencing relationship in `symfony2` / `doctrine`. Similar issue was described here: [Error Symfony2 Doctrine Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association sth#vote, but expecting sth\Vote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042533/error-symfony2-doctrine-found-entity-of-type-doctrine-common-collections-arrayco) but no solution was provided.

I go the following exception:

> Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on
>   association AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria#corka, but expecting
>   AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria

This error seems to be occurring during execution of script listed below. It seems a bit strange as **I am trying to update relation based on data get by findOneBy doctrine function which should return me entity not an array**.

```
$Corka = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Kategoria')->findOneByNazwa($row["nazwa"]);
$Ojciec = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Kategoria')->findOneByNazwa($result[$row["rodzicId"]]["nazwa"]);
if(!$Corka) die ("Critical error: Corka: ".$row["nazwa"]."not found");
if(!$Ojciec) die ("Critical error: Ojciec: ".$result[$row["rodzicId"]]["nazwa"]."not found");
$Ojciec->addCorka($Corka);
```

My kategoria.php:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kategoria", inversedBy="rodzic")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rodzic", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
    private $corka;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Kategoria", mappedBy="corka")
     **/
    private $rodzic;

/**
     * Add corka
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria $corka
     * @return Kategoria
     */
    public function addCorka(\AppBundle\Entity\Kategoria $corka)
    {
        $this->corka[] = $corka;

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this error was caused by wrong annotations in entity self-referencing association mapping.

Correct mapping annotations may be found here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

In my case they were:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kategoria", inversedBy="corka")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rodzic", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
    private $rodzic;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ksiazka", mappedBy="kategoria")
     **/
      protected $ksiazka;
```